# Kentico and ASP.Net MVC Custom Routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, kentico

Is there a way to get an MVC route in Kentico to process multiple URL parameters within a single URL segment?

Example:
I'm trying to route to 
`/base/{param1}-{param2}`
I'd also like to be able to route to `/base/{param1}`
Also, {param2} may contain one or more '-' characters...
An example route would be: `/base/1234-jon-doe-something-or-another`
This would ideally be fed into Kentico with param1 set to `1234` and param2 set to `jon-doe-something-or-another`

Is this possible?

The reason for the weird route is duplicating legacy functionality.

Comment: You're going to need two separate routes with constraints. `base/{param1:int}` and `base/{param1:int}-{*param2}`

Comment: I had to use /base/{param} and separate the parameters in the consuming component. This works, with the caveat of requiring a one-off web part.

Answer (score 0):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Your route",
    url: "/base/{param1}-{*param2}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Foo", action = "Index" }
);
```

Then in your `FooController.cs`

```
public ActionResult Index(string param1, string param2)
{
    // Do something with param1
    // Do something with param2
}
```

Now `param2` will take everything after the first dash `'-'`.

You can keep structuring your url in the route if you want to add to the end of it, e.g.
`url: "/base/{param1}-{*param2}/more/routing",`